# Addthis in iOS7 64bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, addthis

I am developing my iOS app and using Addthis library but error.

**error message:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AddThisSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "`libAddThis.a`" doesn't have 64-bit support built in, that's why you are currently seeing the "`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`" error.

You won't be able to support 64-bit in your application, at least until AddThis updates their SDK to support 64-bit iOS.

So for the time being you should:

1) turn off "`arm64`" from the "valid architectures" & "architectures" in your app's build settings

2) e-mail the AddThis support people (e.g. via the "Post A Question" link on their [iOS SDK page](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide))and tell them to update their SDK to support 64-bit iOS.